# Firestore How to access a value from a snapshot in a Document Snapshot stream

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to dart/flutter and am building an app right now that keeps track of some data on each user in a firstore database. I have a 'Users' collection which contains a document for each user, and one of the fields in the user document is the "UID" received through firebase_auth.

That being said, to make sure I have access to the latest copy of a user document, I hold a Stream. I want to somehow access the "UID" field from the latest snapshot in the stream and then do some other operations with it.

Is there anyway to do this? Am I using/understanding streams incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever need the UID to build other widgets, you can simply use a [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) which will rebuild its children whenever a new value is emitted from the stream (which you get a copy of). However, if you need to access the latest UID at some arbitrary point of time, check out RxDart's [`BehaviorSubject`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html) which provides constant-time synchronous access to the latest emitted value, if one exists. It is very helpful for handling state in general.

Comment: Would this allow me to listen to changes in a subcollection? Right now, each of my user documents has a subcollection "Friends", where this sub collection contains documents that solely contain the UID of a friend. I would like to get the most up to date list of friend UIDs

Comment: Yes, `BehaviorSubject` can act as a wrapper around a stream using its `addStream` function, while also serving as a stream itself. It just provides a `value` field that is a cached version of the last emitted value that you can use to get the last emitted value at any point in time. As a heads up, if you're looking to combine 2+ streams into a singular stream that has the latest elements from each stream, look at RxDart's `combineLatest` methods.